# Chef Client cannot find a resource for apt_update on ubuntu version 14.04

Tags: chef-infra

I am going through the official chef documentation to learn about chef and trying to bootstrap a node but encountering some errors which I am not able top figure out:

[image]

I am also wondering why it shows the Chef client version as 11.6.2 where as I have 
C:\Users\<--->\learn-chef>chef --version
Chef Development Kit Version: 3.4.38
chef-client version: 14.6.47
delivery version: master (6862f27aba89109a9630f0b6c6798efec56b4efe)
berks version: 7.0.6
kitchen version: 1.23.2
inspec version: 3.0.12

I am new to chef and already have spent 5-6 hourse to fix this but can't figure out what's the issue here.

Comment: How do you bootstrap the chef node? Please paste exact commands and relevant config files.

Answer (score 0):

the remote node (usually the node that is being bootstrapped and then converged) chef version could be different than the chef version on your local node. be sure that you bootstrap chef correctly.

if you [install chef omnibus via url](https://docs.chef.io/install_omnibus.html#install-script-options), then utilize the `-v` option to specify the version. for instance

```
$ curl -L https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -v 14.4.56
```

otherwise, you can use [`chef-client updater`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef_client_updater#examples) cookbook and utilize the `version`. for instance

```
chef_client_updater 'Install latest Chef 13.x' do
  version '13'
end
```